# Foursquare venues/explore api not returning data when friendVisits=visited query parameter is set

Tags: foursquare

In the foursquare api document for venues/explore specified here https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore it specifies that if you include `friendVisits=visited`, it would return results of venues your friends have visited, however, I always get zero results, although I know that my friends have checked in at venues near the location I've specified.  Is this functionality no longer supported or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [authorize](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) your application and use an `access_token` instead of `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing exactly that. I'm authorized and passing in `oauth_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`. i am not using `client_id` and `client_secret`

Comment: This is working fine for me with this API call: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?oauth_token=****&v=20151101&near=san francisco, ca&friendVisits=visited&query=bars

Comment: I played around with the query parameters after looking at your response. Looks like it only returns results if you specify a `query`. I was using `section`, which does not return results. Is this a limitation? I did not see any mention of that in the docs.  ex. `query=bars` returns results but `section=drinks` does not.

Comment: I noticed this behavior too. This could be a bug, but using `query` over `section` should return nearly the same results.